# Create Login with responsive background image

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to create a login page in angular which has a background image and is responsive.
But when I do it the Image does not appear.

Can anyone please help me!

Code URL - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-esdxku

Answer (score 1):

You can save the image in assets folder and can access it by:

Always starting with "/assets/" in CSS and "assets/" in HTML.

CSS

```
.bg-img {
  display: grid;

  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("/assets/portalLogin.svg") 

  /* Control the height of the image */
  min-height: 980px;
  width: auto;

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your image should be inside assets folder, and you should give a path of image from assets folder.